# php xpath get HTML element + neighbor element if exist

Tags: php, xpath

How do I get an HTML element with a specified class along with its neighbor and save it in HTML?

this is my php. this works properly, but returns me only element with the specified class. This code finds in the list of items that have the class I'm looking for and returns the HTML content. But I do not return the element that is in the item as well.
Namely my php returns only element `<a href="">` with the class `cf_sel_opt`, but I also need to get neighbor hidden `<input>`.

```
foreach ($filters_render_array['html'] as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'custom_f_') !== false) {
        $html = new DOMDocument();
        $html->loadHTML($value);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($html);
        $elements = $xpath->query('//li/*[contains(@class,"cf_sel_opt")]');
        if (!is_null($elements)) {
          foreach ($elements as $element) {
                $array[] = $html->saveHTML($element);
          }
        }
    }
}
if(!empty($array)) { ?>
    <div class="filter-reset">
        <a class="cf_resetAll_link" rel="nofollow" data-module-id="<?php echo $module->id ?>" href="<?php echo JRoute::_($resetUri)?>">
            <span class="cf_resetAll_label"><?php 
                echo JText::_('MOD_CF_RESET_ALL')?>
            </span>
        </a>
        <div><?php
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($array as $sel_item) {
                echo "<li>" . $sel_item . "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";   ?>
        </div>
    </div><?php 
} ?>
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
   <a href="#" class="cf_option  cf_color_btn cf_sel_opt" rel="nofollow" data-module-id="129" id="custom_f_35_129_elid313038_a" style="">
      <span class="cf_color_inner" style="background-color:black; width:100%;">
      </span>
   </a>
   <input name="custom_f_35[]" value="313038" type="hidden">
</li>
</ul>
```

**ANSWER**

For anyone who will have a similar problem I have found a functional solution.
I modified my query from this:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//li/*[contains(@class,"cf_sel_opt")]);
```

to this:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//li/*[contains(@class,"cf_sel_opt")]/ancestor::li[1]');
```

Comment: Why not get his parent and work with that, you can use a selector like: `//li[./a[contains(@class, 'cf_sel_opt')]]`  now you have the `li` that contains the link with your class.

Comment: Because this was a quick fix :) when it works, I did not look for other options